# How to insert large amount of data in a MySQL table without LOAD DATA INFILE?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a CSV file with around 1.8million rows. I need to insert them into a MySQL table from my PHP script. I am inserting the values in batches of 10,000.
The scripts run for very long time and crashes after inserting 80-95 batches. I have tried mysql_unbuffered_query() also but of no use.

```
if ($fp) {
        $batch = 1;
        $row_count = 1;
        $bucket_counter = 1;
        $mobile_numbers = array();
        $row_count_for_DB_write = 0;
        foreach ($campaign_numbers as $value) {
            $number = array($value);
            fputcsv($fp, $number);
            $row_count_for_DB_write++;
            $value_row = new stdClass();
            $value_row->number = $value;
            $value_row->bucket_number = $bucket_counter;
            $mobile_numbers[] = $value_row;
            if ($row_count == $bucket_size && $bucket_counter < $bucket_count) {
                $bucket_counter++;
                $row_count = 1;
                fclose($fp);
                $fp = fopen($directory . "/cn_$bucket_counter.csv", 'w');
                $logger->debug('Created csv file : ' . $directory . '/cn_$bucket_counter.csv');
            }

            if ($row_count_for_DB_write == CONSTANTS::BATCH_SIZE) {
                $logger->debug($batch." Batch insert starting at: ".date('d-m-Y_H-i-s', time()));
                $insert_count = $data_service->add_to_mobile_numbers_table($mobile_numbers_table, $mobile_numbers);
                $batch++;
                $logger->debug("Batch insert ending at: ".date('d-m-Y_H-i-s', time()));
                $row_count_for_DB_write = 1;
                unset($mobile_numbers);
                $mobile_numbers = array();
            }
            $row_count++;
        }
    }
    fclose($fp);
    $data_service->add_to_mobile_numbers_table($mobile_numbers_table, $mobile_numbers);
    $zip_file = "/$directory_name.zip";
    $logger->debug('Creating zipped file');
    Util::create_zip(Util::get_list_of_files($directory), $directory . $zip_file);
```

Comment: what error you are getting ? which PHP version are you using ?

Comment: is this a 1 time process or you need to upload csv files every now and then? if not why don't you just upload a .sql file which contains the insert query for all the records in your csv file into your server and call that .sql file from the mysql console to insert into the database

Comment: This process has moderate frequency. Like twice a week or so. I am using PHP 5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following steps solved this issue:

- Change table engine from InnoDB to MyISAM
- disable the keys
- insert data
- re-enable the keys